# Merging non-adjacent partitions

Tags: partitioning, windows, encryption, gparted

I have some unallocated partition that I want to merge with my partition containing Windows (nvme0n1p6). I don't want to lose the data in Windows, but as long as other partitions are unaffected, I am OK with losing Windows data if that is my only option.

GParted:

[image: gparted screenshot]

I read that merging when not adjacent is hard, and I couldn't find a proper solution online.

Comment: "Merging when not adjacent" is not only "hard" it's impossible. The data structures for disk partitions don't allow discontinuous partitions. Being aware of the Primary/Extended nature of partitions, you will have to move partitions around until the unallocated space is adjacent to `nvme0n1p6`.

Answer (score 0):

As @waltinator wrote, you can't merge those partitions into one. But you can use the Windows disk manager to create a new Windows drive from that partition.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case, creating a new disk is also a valid option. So I will do that.